# json and php interegation

Tags: php, json, getjson

I use getJson() function to dynamically retrieve content from server with php. The code is like this:

```
function loadContent(url){
        $.getJSON("content.php", {cid: url, format: 'json'}, function(json) {
                $.each(json, function(key, value){
                    $(key).html(value);
                });
            });
        }
```

content.php gets some data from mysql and generates an array and encodes it to json format array, then with JavaScript I print it in main_page.html. What I want to do is the output of content.php to be one string (or one line in array) with html code (combined with data from mysql). Because I don't want to print just an array. For example I want the content.php output to be something like this:

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="one">
  some html code combined with data from mysql.
  </div>
  <div id="two">
  some html code combined with data from mysql.
  </div>
  .
  .
  .
</div>
```

and all of this to print it in a `<div id="main"> ..output of content.php.. </div>` in main_page.html. So the json function doesn't have to loop this code 
`$.each(json, function(key, value){
                    $(key).html(value);}`
and do one print at all.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, then you can use $.get() to achieve desired result.

```
function loadContent(url){
    $.get( "content.php", {cid: url}, function( data ) {
        $( "#content" ).html( data );
    });
}
```

And modify your content.php to return plain html instead of json encoded data.

```
<?php
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT name FROM items");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
$i = 1;

foreach($result as $item) {
    echo '<div id="item' . $i . '">' . $item['name'] . '</div>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks man it worked fine! But i have another problem now. I use pushstate() and popstate() to virtually make history links in browser (combined with the get(url)). To work with the above code i made all links to parse the value to content.php. For example
`<a href="1">...</a>` so the content.php gets id=1. But the browser shows www.mysite.com/1 and when i refresh the page it shows a 404 becuase is trying to find the file 1. I want the www.mysite.com/1 to parse the '1' to content.php and the link to be 
`<a href=/1>...</a>` (or the same as above idont mind about this).

Comment: You can use .htaccess for that to rewrite everything after content.php in url to id.

Comment: I have two pages. The main page is index.php and another one is content.php that produces the data to retrieve in index.php with get(url). How is it possible to show index.php when you visit www.mysite.com. And when you visit www.mysite.com/1234 to show index.php and retrieve data from content.php with id=1234 ? This is done with .htaccess? do you know what code .htaccess must have?

Comment: i m trying to do something like this: http://html5.gingerhost.com/
If you see the code you ll see that it uses content.php to produse data but if you visit content.php?id=London it show only the text and if you visit http://html5.gingerhost.com/London it shows whole site with the data from content.php inside. That 's what i m trying to do